# Change from select to value assignment

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am having difficulty enhancing my code to remove the "SELECT" option and use the ASSIGNMENT. Meaning to change from the SELECT, COPY and PASTE to the assigning Values Directly. I am an absolute beginner, if anyone could lead me through. My main issue is in the loop, however, here is the full code, any suggestion, recommendation is welcomed, just to make it more efficient!

Here is my code:

```
Sub LINK_ANALYSIS()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

Dim NumberOfColumns As Integer
Dim rng As Range


NumberOfColumns = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value2
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B2").Value2 = "SUBJECT"

Let x = 4

Do While x <= NumberOfColumns


ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=x, Criteria1:="1", Criteria2:="2", Operator:=xlOr

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(2, x).Select

Set rng = Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column))


rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Select




If ActiveCell.Value >= "1" Then

       Cells(1, (x - 1)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("A1").Select


End If

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=x

x = x + 2


Loop

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select


Sheets("Sheet2").Copy


    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: in your code you have an example of assignment `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B2").Value2 = "SUBJECT"`. When you use `SELECT` in VBA it is like you are clicking on the cell. So if you knew exactly what cell you want, just state it/them and say what value you want to assign. (exactly what you did). It takes a little getting used to the syntax as you may be trying to navigate between sheets. Good luck.

Comment: [This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)